# Angular mat-slider material v17 Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, mat-slider, angular17

I've been in the process of migrating legacy components within my Angular application material v17, and I've encountered an issue with the  component when integrating it with reactive forms.
When attempting to utilize  with a reactive form control, I'm encountering the error message:
**Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute**

```
<mat-slider color="primary"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            step="1"
            discrete
            showTickMarks>
  <input formControlName="max_retries" matSliderThumb/>
</mat-slider>
```

-There's only a single instance of  being used in the template.

-The error arises specifically when adding the formControlName="max_retries" attribute to the  element inside  for the purpose of binding it to a reactive form.

-No custom ControlValueAccessor implementations have been created for this component.

Comment: try give name to the input: `<input name="max_retries" formControlName="max_retries" matSliderThumb/>` or reorder the directives:`<input matSliderThumb formControlName="max_retries" />`. Sorry I'm in hurry to check if this solutionate something :(

Comment: Seems to be working on a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nnzjig) forked from examples. You'll probably have provide some kind of repro.

Comment: @Eliseo  I've tried, but the problem persists.

Comment: Has you import the ReactiveFormsModule in your component (if it's standalone) or in the module where you declare the component (if not standalone)? Are you sure the code is under a formGroup?

Comment: Yes, other components are functioning properly

Comment: Are you able to post some of the .component.ts code?